# How to type 'prepare' function in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-actions

I am using redux-toolkit `prepare` function to construct the final payload value.

```js
    addTodo: {
      reducer: (state, action) => {
        state.push(action.payload);
      },
      // ERROR: **Type '{ payload: Todo; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>, "type">': meta, errorts**
      prepare: (todoMessage: string): { payload: Todo } => {
        return {
          payload: { message: todoMessage, id: uuid(), completed: false }
        };
      }
    },
```

How can I type `prepare` function to remove the typescript error?

Check the error [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-worker-upxstj?file=/src/store/todos.ts).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    addTodo: {
      reducer: (state, action: PayloadAction<Todo>) => {
        state.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare: (todoMessage: string) => {
        return {
          payload: { message: todoMessage, id: uuid(), completed: false }
        };
      }
    },
```

you just need to add a payload type on the `action`.

Comment: Thanks man, exactly what I was looking for :) Do you mind explaining why the error was there in the first place, and why this fixes it?

Comment: @MichaelVigato Because the return value of `prepare` and the `action` argument of `reducer` need to have the same type. The return value of `prepare` can be inferred by TypeScript (all types are known here), but the input value to `reducer` cannot be inferred - you'll have to specify that manually or it will fall back to some generic fallback that will cause you errors.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is also a [TypeScript example in the `createSlice` api documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#customizing-generated-action-creators) showcasing how to type this.